# How to know if a web service has started

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, jboss

I have the following scenario:

- There is a web service hosted on jBoss.
- The web service is used by a java application.

Now the usual startup scenario is :

- jBoss starts and loads the web app.
- The application is then started and it uses the web service.

Now the problem:

In case the Java application starts first, is there any way for it to know that the web service has started?

I thought of pinging the web service regularly but that is likely to have quiet some overhead. Any solution is welcome.

Comment: is it soap or rest style?

Comment: Just try to use it. If it isn't there you will get the appropriate exception.

Comment: @EPJ Yes I do get appropriate exception. But what I need is a way to find out if the web service starts later so that the application can have a normal boot-up automatically.

Comment: Why? What difference is it going to make? Either it is available when you need to call it, or it isn't. If it isn't, you need to cope with the resulting failure. Whether that's because of startup order or network failure or nuclear explosion really makes no difference at all. The only sensible way to determine the availability of *any* resource is to try to use it, in the normal course of program execution. Anything else and you're introducing timing windows, trying to predict the future, ...

Comment: The application requires the web service to during start up. Now if I want that instead of just stopping the start-up, I wait for the service to start then what other way do I have? If I don't have to restart the app in case of a failure then isn't it good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pinging" the web service regularly is not a big overhead. Why would it be?

Just wait a little between retries. A common strategy is to increase the wait time between tries up to a maximum. E.g. try and if not ready, wait 1 sec, then try again and if still not ready, wait 2 sec, then 4 sec etc. up to like max 8 sec between retries.

Meanwhile display a message to the user like:

```
"Waiting for web service to start..."
```

Optionally including the number of attempts made so far like:

```
"Waiting for web service to start... (retrying #2)"
```

Also alternatively you can make a small, static text file available as part of of the webapp like "ping.txt" and try to get that as your test whether the app is ready and available, you don't have to call the webservice itself. It can also point to a `Servlet` in which case you can make sure the servlet container is also up (of course disable caching of this ping url).

Also as an another alternative if your webservice module has significant time to stand up, the target of the "ping" may be the wsdl document of the webservice. Most webservice frameworks provide a way to access/download the dynamically generated WSDL document of the webservice. If that URL responds and sends back the dynamic WSDL document, the wsdl module is also up.

Comment: Thanks. I too feel the same, pinging is a simple solution and should work fine. But I was still wondering if there is any other approach to it. You know like a response from the web service or some other idea. 
Seems I will stick to pinging for now.

Comment: Even if some test says the service is up, there's still a chance it will become unreachable if you proceed to call it after that, so there isn't really a better option. Also added another alternative to ping-target the dynamic wsdl document.

Comment: It may or may not be an overhead but it is also unreliable. The ping may succeed and the call fail. Or the ping may fail and the call succeed. The ping is therefore basically pointless. The success or failure of the actual call is all that matters.

Comment: @EJP As you said: "it may or may not be an overhead". If it is an overhead, it can be profitable to ping other "lightweight" resources. If it is not, the "ping" itself may target the webservice as well, I never said it can't be that (that's why I quoted the "ping" word everywhere). And yes, the ws call might fail after a successful "ping", but the primary goal here was just to test if the webapp is up and running, and not to check other conditions of a successful webservice call.

Comment: But why? You don't care if it's up and running unless you call it. It can go up and down like a yoyo at other times, and your application should let it do so rather than prevent it. Consider the TCP model: exactly the same. Routers can go up and down willy-billy without disturbing the connection. This is why TCP works, and why SNA and friends are no longer with us. All the extra pings do is introduce extra and more complex failure modes. It's pointless.

Comment: I am not sure if you actually understood the problem. The app can handle the web service going up or down, but it is required at startup. And I did not want the user to go through the trouble of restarting the app once the web service is up. Sothis is what I did ultimately : checked on startup, if web service not available then wait for it and check by 'pinging', once up resume normal startup.

Comment: marking this as the answer cos this seems the straightest way forward.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cater for connectivity problems in your client application at all times - not just startup, therefore there is no point in "pinging". This applies to any kind of remote connectivity solution.

When it's time to call the service just call it. If it's down the connection will fail and you can inform the user in an appropriate way. You must do this whether you ping or not, as the service may disappear between the last ping and your actual call.

The remote service could go up and down any number of times while the client is active.

Comment: True. But how do I regularly check the connection status without pinging?

Comment: You don't. Just try to use the service whenever you need it. You don't care whether it's available when you don't need it, and when you do need it the only reliable way to test it is to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check logs from var/log/..../access.log
    eg. tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log